# Ab amplifier input buffer with transistors

Tags: transistors

In the folowing scheme what are the D1,D2,D3 diodes, the R9 resistence and the pot2 potenciometer doing?[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *what are the D1,D2,D3 diodes, the R9 resistance and the pot2
> potentiometer doing?*

They create a "fairly" stable voltage difference between the bases of Q3 and Q4 that is sufficient to cause some collector current to flow in both pairs of output transistors thus, alleviating the effects of cross-over distortion.

You set up the collector current with the potentiometer and an ammeter or power supply with inbuilt current display.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the circuit you show will thermally run away and self-destruct *unless* Q5, Q6, Q3, Q4, D1, D2, D3 are all well coupled to the same heatsink.

Since D1, D2 and D3 are shown to be glass-packaged 1N4148 types, it's not practical to ensure good thermal bonding between them and the heatsink.

Instead, D1-D3 can be TO-126 packaged, diode-connected "medium power" transistors - it's easy to mount them on a heatsink, and they will do the job as well as is possible under the circumstances.